# NSRangeException while using substringWithRange:NSMakeRange

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsrangeexception

I'm having an odd error I don't understand.  I've looked at other questions, and I see that NSMakeRange is anchor, distance to traverse.  This single statement causes a NSRangeException, out of bounds error though:

```
    if([myCompare characterAtIndex:([myCompare length]-7) == 'N'])
    {
        [myTemp appendString:[myCompare substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,([myCompare length]-7))]];
    }
```

In this case, I don't understand how it could EVER be out of range, since I'm always subtracting 7 from the length of the NSString and making THAT that range.

It might be a stupid error, but I would appreciate another set of eyes to figure out why that is causing my NSRangeException.

Comment: It will be out of range if myCompare is less than 7 characters long.

Comment: Aye, it dawned on me not too long after posting this.  I just had to walk away from the keyboard a while.  I was in a situation where I was never being passed less than 7, and then suddenly I was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you misplace your "]"

```
if([myCompare length] >= 7 && [myCompare characterAtIndex:([myCompare length]-7)] == 'N')
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  It was just one of those eyes glazed over things.